# Copy one row and pastespecial values row to another sheet (or just part of row)

Tags: excel, vba, paste

PasteValues is the most frustrating thing in VBA! Could greatly use some help.
In short, I am trying to copy one row and pastespecial values that row into another row on a separate sheet. I thought it was a row issue, so I then modified my range and tried pasting that, also to no avail. I even tried recording a macro and the generated code is almost the exact same as mine.

Can someone please help? I've been looking at this too long :/

```
Sub CopyXs()

Dim counter As Double
Dim CopyRange As String
Dim NewRange As String

counter = 2

For Each Cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LD_Tracker_CEPFA").Range("A7:A500")
If Cell.Value = "X" Then
Sheets("Upload_Sheet").Select
matchrow = Cell.Row
counter = counter + 1



Let CopyRange = "A" & matchrow & ":" & "Y" & matchrow
Let NewRange = "A" & counter & ":" & "Y" & counter

Range(CopyRange).Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Final_Upload").Select
ActiveSheet.Range(NewRange).Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste = xlPasteValues

Sheets("Upload_Sheet").Select
End If

Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Try `:=xlPasteValues` instead of `=xlPasteValues`

Comment: @JasonKowalski Welcome to SO. In general it is best practice to answer questions as an Answer, and not to edit your question to contain the answer. I've re-edited your question to remove the answer. Either you or Matt Cremeens should add the solution in the Answer section.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling also with Paste.Special. This code works for me. The code you get when you record a macro for Paste.Special is not working. You first have to define a range and then used the code for Paste.Special

Range(something).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

```
'This code works for me:    
'**Select everything on the active sheet**

Range("A1").Select
Dim rangeTemp As Range
Set rngTemp = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
If Not rngTemp Is Nothing Then Range(Cells(4, 1), rngTemp).Select
End if

 ' **Copy the selected range**
Selection.Copy

'**Select the destination and go to the last cel in column A and then go 2 cells down
'and paste the values**

Sheets("your sheet name").Select
Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

    **'Select the last cell in column A**

Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
```